# Progress Bar Implementation for CodeGen in Theia

Tags: xtext, theia, theia-ide

on clicking generate java code button in theia editor
it’s calling registry command in command contribution in theia.
registry command is hitting IExecutableCommandService in backend LSP to generate java code.

now i need value of execution progress in theia editor so that i can implement that in progress bar.

Comment: you are welcome to implement and contribute progress support in Xtext LSP

Comment: see also https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-core/issues/1920